# zerofill method using java

Tags: java, zerofill

I want my `textfield` become like this `“99999”`

this is my code

```
while (rs.next()){
    int s=rs.getInt("Number");
    String num1 = String.valueOf(s);
    String n = String.format("%05d",num1);
    view.txtcustomernumber.setText(n);
}
```

why my `txtcustomernumber(JTextField)` always blank

Comment: Have you tried printing out some debug statements?  For example, what is the value of `s`? Or `num1`?  Or of `n`?  If you do this you could probably trace back the cause.  Maybe a bug means this part of the code is never even executed!

Comment: sorry typo i already remove the C

Comment: i already try debug statement its nothing at bug statement but still blank

Comment: @YuukiRito What is blank?  The `int` variables can't be blank, tell us where it goes wrong.  Is the value of `s` correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
while (rs.next()){
int s=rs.getInt("Number");
String n = String.format("%05d",s);
view.txtcustomernumber.setText(n);
}
```

It might solve your problem.

Comment: That's a good point - I'm pretty sure OP's code should generate an exception at runtime actually due to the `String` being placed in a `%d` field, which he hasn't mentioned...

Comment: yea @jazzbassrob, that's the reason i skipped that line and it works perfectly fine. :)